# Error in spring security config class

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

In my spring app, I am using Spring 4.0.4 and Spring Security 3.2.3. I copied this code directly from a tutorial on the sprin website but I am having problem compiling because the method `registerAuthentication` couldn't be overriden from the  `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` class and the `HttpSecurity` class doesn't have the methode `authorizeUrls`. Is there a jar I'm missing? Or is it the version?

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;


@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void registerAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("letsnosh").password("noshing").roles("USER");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeUrls()
                .antMatchers("/order/**").hasRole("USER")
                .antMatchers("/checkout").hasRole("USER")
                .anyRequest().anonymous()
                .and()
                //This will generate a login form if none is supplied.
                .formLogin();
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Looks like this is now `.authorizeRequests()` as of **3.2.0.RC1** .  See https://jira.spring.io/browse/SEC-2202

Answer (score 3):

Now it is `.authorizeRequests()`

Answer (score 0):

I have the same code and it works fine for me. Have you checked that you have both spring-security-web and spring-security-config in your classpath? Try to add them to your dependency section (if you are using maven).

```
<!-- Spring security -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

To get that section of that tutorial to run with gradle, it uses

```
compile 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:3.2.0.M2'
compile 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:3.2.0.M2'
compile 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:3.2.0.M2'
```

I'm not sure what later versions would do.

Also, be aware that the `.anyRequest().anonymous()` line will lock out all pages except order and checkout once your logged in since you're no longer anonymous.  Just remove that line for it to work the way the tutorial expects it to.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("letsnosh").password("noshing").roles("USER");
}
```